# Upload large files failed when using nginx and zuul

Tags: java, nginx, netflix-zuul

I deployed a nginx in the frontend, and zuul gateway for transfer.

When I try to post a file larger than 100MB, nginx returns 504 after about 5m24s, while the zuul gateway is still transferring the data to the microservice.

I tried the /zuul mode, got the same results.

If post the file directly to zuul, it succeededs, as I have adjusted the zuul related parameters.

I found many ways to change the delay time for nginx, for instance, in nginx.conf

```
proxy_connect_timeout 600s;
proxy_send_timeout 600s;
proxy_read_timeout 600s;
send_timeout 600s;
```

Tried all, none of them worked.

So, did I miss something or is there another solution to my problem?

Comment: Can you edit this question to be a bit more readable? It looks like a meaningful question otherwise.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To improve your questions, please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).